# How to schedule the CRON to be run 1 to 1:30?

Tags: cron, apache-nifi, cron-task, crontrigger

I need to know cron expression to run every monday between 1 and 1:30 am.

I have tried below  expressions not worked.

```
1 * 1-2 ? * MON *
```

Can anyone help me to write cron expression?

Comment: There is no Monday between 1 and 1:30, only minutes.

Comment: am new to CRON. am just need to schedule the job to be run every monday between 1 to 1:30.

Comment: Do you mean every minute between 1 and 1:30? Or every monday on every minute between 1 and 1:30? Or every monday on 1 AND on 1:30? So much possibilities if I have to interpret your question.

Comment: On every monday, run between 1:00AM to 1:30 AM every minutes should run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below expression

```
0 0-30 1 ? * MON *
```

Comment: Good to know that :)
NiFi uses Quartz cron expressions, you can create/test your expressions in the following link.. 
http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `0 0-30 1 ? * MON`

I think, you need at least 6 slots to fill so CRON expression is valid.